# Was there ever a president of the united states related to more than 1 other president?

Tags: united-states, president, family

I know that george bush and his father were presidents, as well as John Adams (I think), is there any president of the USA who was biologically related to 2 or more other presidents?

Comment: How far back in the family tree do you define as "related"? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_family

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy good question, uh... I guess where one of their known ancestors was an ancestor of another president

Comment: Simply googling 'US presidents related to other presidents' turns up several sites at the top of the first page. See, for example, [Genealogical relationships of Presidents of the United States](https://familypedia.wikia.org/wiki/Genealogical_relationships_of_Presidents_of_the_United_States) and [U.S. Presidents Who Were Related to Each Other](https://www.infoplease.com/us/government/executive-branch/us-presidents-who-were-related-to-each-other).

Comment: @LarsBosteen dang, looking into it I found this https://curiousmindmagazine.com/all-us-presidents-including-trump-are-descendants-of-the-same-english-king/

Answer (score 6):

Obviously at some level it's a degenerate question, because ultimately every human on earth is related.

So given that we are really good at genealogy these days, it probably shouldn't be surprising that there are oodles of them that we know of.

Looking over [the link provided by Lars](https://familypedia.wikia.org/wiki/Genealogical_relationships_of_Presidents_of_the_United_States) in the comments, it looks like the closest related triple were Madison, Polk, and Taylor who were second cousins (once removed in the case of Taylor and Polk).

Even Obama has known relation to three other presidents. James Madison was his third cousin<sup>9</sup>, LBJ his fourth<sup>3</sup>, and Carter his eighth<sup>2</sup>.

Going past that, frankly It would be much easier easier to list those who *don't* have two known relations. Those are (listed in order with presidency number):

- 1 Washington
- 3 Jefferson
- 5 Monroe<sup>*</sup>
- 7 Jackson
- 13 Filmore
- 15 Buchanan
- 17 A. Johnson
- 21 Arthur
- 28 Wilson
- 34 Eisenhower
- 35 Kennedy
- 36 LBJ<sup>*</sup>
- 40 Reagan
- 42 Clinton

You might notice that the pace slows down towards the end. That makes a certain amount of sense, as the genealogical fan-in increases as you move down generations.

Still, that's only 14 of the 45 Presidents.

<sup>* - Related to one other POTUS, but not two</sup>

<sup>Numeric Superscripts designate level of removal</sup>

Comment: Not sure I got this list 100% correct (as there was a lot of data to reconcile), so wouldn't mind some backstopping. But It should be close.

Comment: If you read Lars's links more closely, you will see that if you count relationships by marriage you can certainly remove Jefferson and Wilson from that list (combining with the next comment to get the 3rd relation).  If it doesn't have to be a presidential marriage, but a relative of one who married a relative of the other, then you can also remove Eisenhower.

Comment: Also, if you allow very distant cousins, you can remove Washington, Jefferson, and Monroe, based on common descent from Edward III.

Comment: @CMonsour - In the absence of a question clarification otherwise, I made  the decision, in this answer at least, not to include relationships by marriage (although it would make things much simpler, as it would make all relationships transitive). Its possible I screwed that up early on in the list though, which is one of the reasons I appreciate double-checking.

Comment: You still probably ought to delete Washington, Jefferson, and Monroe, as they have an identifiable common ancestor from the 1300s.

Comment: @CMonsour - Well, again if you don't draw the line somewhere its a degenerate question. The furthest back ancestor I know of that caused a "relation" on the source for this list lived 1610-1660 (Madison's great-great grandfather). I'm not sure how much further back than that it would be reasonable to draw the line, but my gut tells me that was actually stretching it a bit, and prancing across the era boundary into the Middle Ages would be too far.